# extension "pg_buffercache" already exists and relation "pg_buffercache" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.5

When I try to create the extension `pg_buffercahe` using the following command:

```
➤ psql://postgres@postgresql-95-2:5432/postgres 

CREATE EXTENSION pg_buffercache;
```

...it returns the error:

```
ERROR:  extension "pg_buffercache" already exists
```

If I try to retrieve information from the `pg_buffercahe` using the following command:

```
➤ psql://postgres@postgresql-95-2:5432/postgres 

select count(*) from pg_buffercache where not isdirty;
```

...I receive the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "pg_buffercache" does not exist
```

The following packages are installed on my system:

```
yum list postgresql95*  
Installed Packages
postgresql95.x86_64         9.5.10-1PGDG.rhel7
postgresql95-contrib.x86_64 9.5.10-1PGDG.rhel7
postgresql95-libs.x86_64    9.5.10-1PGDG.rhel7
postgresql95-server.x86_64  9.5.10-1PGDG.rhel7
```

How can I fix this issue?

➤ psql://postgres@postgresql-95-2:5432/postgres

```
# \dx
                                     List of installed extensions
        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                        Description                        
--------------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 pg_buffercache     | 1.1     | public     | examine the shared buffer cache
 pg_stat_statements | 1.3     | public     | track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
 plpgsql            | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(3 rows)
```

➤ psql://postgres@postgresql-95-2:5432/postgres

```
# select count(*) from pg_buffercache where not isdirty;
ERROR:  relation "pg_buffercache" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) from pg_buffercache where not isdirty;
```

Answer (score 3):

The extension was created in a schema which is not in your `search_path`.  So you can't create another copy of it, but also can't find the view.  You can use `\dx` to find what schema it was installed to.

Comment: Hello. I checked List of installed extensions and i see pg_buffercache installed. But way it dont work? Thank you

Comment: What schema is it installed into (`\dx` will show you that)?  Is that schema in your `search_path`?

Answer (score 0):

The `'relation does not exist'` message is usually displayed when you are not connected to any particular database. Make sure you are connected.

```
/c yourDb
yourDb=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_buffercache;
yourDb=# SELECT count(*) FROM pg_buffercache WHERE isdirty;
```

Comment: My yourDb is postgres. This is default DB.

Comment: Then connected to postgres database execute `\dx` as @jjanes is suggesting to see what extensions are installed under that database.